# Error message saying that the command is somehow outdated Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The following code just gives me an error message that the command is outdated when I try to use it in Discord, anyone know why?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('purge')
        .setDescription('Purge an amount of messages from a channel.')
        .addIntegerOption((option) => {
            return option
                .setName('amount')
                .setDescription('The amount of messages to purge.')
                .setRequired(true)
        }),

    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const amount = args.amount;
        if (amount > 100) {
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, you can only purge up to 100 messages at a time.`);
        }

        const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount });
        message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Purge')
            .setDescription(`Purged ${amount} messages.`)
            .setTimestamp();

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
};
```

I'm kinda getting tired of this command just not working for some reason or another.

Comment: Specifically what error does it give you?

Comment: this code is not helpful, if the command is outdated, it will be in where you're importing and are setting or adding this command. not in the actual command code. Also... are you deploying your commands to a test guild or to all guilds?

Comment: Command outdated usually happens for my if I restart the bot while the command is already typed into the  text box, I just change to a different channel and then go back and the issue is fine.